# Rails: f.submit issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I'm having a small issue with f.submit. I've created a user form. Once filled, one can choose between Employeur and Prestataire. By clicking on the respective button, you should be redirected to the employeur or prestataire form to continue your subscription. But I'm always being redirected to the Prestataire form, even when I click on the employeur button. It's seems like there's an issue on the user controller with:

```
if params[:commit] == "employeur"
```

Or in the User form:

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Employeur', :name => "Employeur" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Prestataire', name: 'prestataire' %>
```

Here I also tried

```
<%= f.submit 'Employeur', {:name => "submit", :value => "Employeur" }%> but it didn't work.
```

User controller:

```
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            if params[:commit] == "Employeur"
            format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
            else 
            format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
            end
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == "employeur"
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If you could solve this mystery, and also help me understand the difference between the first parameter of f.subit, :name, :value I'll be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this:

```
if params[:commit] == "Employeur"
```

Instead of this:

```
if params[:commit] == "employeur"
```

Comment: I also needed to take off the name part. I don't know why, but it's only when I removed it that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`"Employeur"` is not equal to `"employeur"`. Picking one or the other should make this work.